# Cannot rescale bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am tring to implement "extend" button to fit image into chosen boundaries.

```
public void extendS(View v){
        ImageView iv = current;
        double width = gallery.getWidth();
        double hight= gallery.getHeight();

        double aspect = (width+0)/(hight+0);
        Log.d("aspect", "w: "+width+" h: "+hight+" a: "+aspect);
        if (aspect>1){
            hight/=aspect;
        }else{
            width*=aspect;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        Log.d("aspect", "w: "+width+" h: "+hight+" a: "+aspect);
         Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, (int)width, (int)hight);
         iv.setImageBitmap(scale);
```

Error which I recieve: 07-16 12:26:36.855: E/AndroidRuntime(12647): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
this error seems a bit wierd from my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap photo, float x, float y) {

    try {
        // get current bitmap width and height
        int width = photo.getWidth();
        int height = photo.getHeight();

        // determine how much to scale
        float scaleWidth = x / width;
        float scaleHeight = y / height;

        // create the matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bitmap
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // recreate the new bitmap
        Bitmap resizebitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, width,
                height, matrix, false);
        return resizebitmap;

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.gc();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you sollution works but partially. It does not rescale big bitmap whichi does not fit to screeen and after first call it stops to do anything.

Comment: Also aspect ratio is not taken in account

Comment: you can also try this. iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're trying to access data outside the original bitmap's area. You're actually very close, you're just using the wrong Bitmap.createBitmap() function. Try this to create a bitmap from the original source with a different size:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int)width, (int)hight, true);
```

Also, you're doing the aspect ratio wrong. Hint: you don't need to worry about aspect ratio with this code.

Comment: is not there some error? Compiler tells there is not method Bitmap,createBitmap(bitmap,int,int). I dont see such method here to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html . Maybe you mean this method createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)? what should i put to fileter in that case?

Comment: Yes, createScaledBitmap() is what you want - edited answer to correct. `filter` should probably be true for your case, it affects the method used for scaling. With filter set to false, images that have to be scaled up will look blocky.